# Error catching mysql statement in java

Tags: mysql

Hello so i'm trying to code my own type of error catching on a sql statement. On my method add order i want to add some way of stopping someone from selling a product which has no stock. My code below does not yet do that. I can add orders and update the stock amount but i haven't figured out a way of adding an if statement that works.

```
@FXML
public void AddOrder(ActionEvent event) {

String orderID = orderBox.getText();
String customerID = customerBox.getText();
String productID = productBox.getText();
String amount = amountBox.getText();
// String cost = costBox.getText();
String date = dateBox.getText();
PreparedStatement sample;

dc = new Database();

try {
    c = dc.Connect();

    sample = c.prepareStatement("Select stockAmount from inventory WHERE productID = ?");

    ResultSet rs = sample.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {

        Integer amount2 = rs.getInt("Amount");

        if (amount2 <= 0) {

            System.out.println("No stock exists");

        } else {

            query = c.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO ordertable (orderID,customerID,productID,Amount,Date)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
            update = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE inventory set stockAmount = stockAmount-? WHERE productID =?");
            update.setString(1, amount);
            update.setString(2, productID);
            update.execute();
            query.setString(1, orderID);
            query.setString(2, customerID);
            query.setString(3, productID);
            query.setString(4, amount);
            // query.setString(5, cost);
            query.setString(5, date);
            query.executeUpdate();
            // update.executeUpdate();
            Alert confirmation = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Saved");
            // closeConfirmation.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved");
            confirmation.show();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

orderBox.clear();
customerBox.clear();
productBox.clear();
amountBox.clear();

dateBox.clear();
loadDataFromDatabase(event);
}
```

Below is the error i'm getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just having trouble because of that exception, check these lines:

```
    sample = c.prepareStatement("Select stockAmount from inventory WHERE productID = ?");

    ResultSet rs = sample.executeQuery();
```

The query is defined to accept a parameter for productID, but you haven't given it a value prior to executing the statement. You'll need to change the query so that it doesn't require a parameter or assign a value to the parameter, like this:

```
    sample = c.prepareStatement("Select stockAmount from inventory WHERE productID = ?");
    sample.setString(1, productID);
    ResultSet rs = sample.executeQuery();
```

Comment: thankyou for the help. It compiles now and i'm able to execute the rest of the code BUT i'm able to still sell items if their stock amount gets to 0 or below.